# Помогите решить задачу на python3 с использованием словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

В учебных целях требуется обойтись базовыми средствами языка, без импортирования специализированных модулей

**Описание**

В операционных системах семейства Unix пути к файлам имеют следующий вид: `/folder1/folder2/another_folder/filename.ext`. Они начинаются с символа «/» (слэш), затем идут имена вложенных папок, разделённые этим же символом. Например, в нашем примере папка `another_folder` вложена в папку `folder2`, которая, в свою очередь, вложена в папку `folder1`. В конце, после последнего слэша, идёт имя файла и расширение («filename.ext»), разделённые точкой.

Вам поручено написать систему распределения доступа к файлам. Она должна не пускать пользователя к тем файлам, прочитать которые у него не хватает прав.

Права пользователю можно выдавать как на отдельный файл, так и на целую папку. Например, можно разрешить читать только файл `/folder1/folder2/another_folder/filename.ext`, а можно разрешить читать всю папку `/folder1/folder2/` и тогда пользователь сможет автоматически прочитать любой файл в этой папке, в любой её подпапке и так далее.

Вашей программе выдан список разрешений и запросов. Для каждого запроса скажите, имеет ли право пользователь читать этот файл. Пользователь имеет право читать файл, если ему явно разрешили читать именно этот файл, или если ему разрешили читать любую из папок, в которых находится этот файл. В примере выше пользователь может читать файл `filename.ext`, если ему разрешили читать его или если ему разрешили читать одну из папок `/folder1`, `/folder1/folder2`, `/folder1/folder2/another_folder`.

**Формат ввода**

В первой строчке дано целое число N (1 ≤ N ≤ 1000) — количество выданных разрешений. В следующих N строчках записаны пути, которые пользователю разрешено читать. Путь может содержать только латинские буквы (заглавные и строчные), символ подчёркивания (_), точку и слэш. Гарантируется, что подпапка и файл в одной папке не могут иметь одинаковое название.

В следующей строчке дано целое число M (1 ≤ M ≤ 1000) — количество запросов. В следующих M строчках записаны пути, для которых запрашивается доступ пользователя.

**Формат вывода**

Для каждого запроса выведите в отдельной строке «YES» или «NO» (без кавычек). Выведите «YES», если пользователь сможет прочитать этот файл (то есть ему был выдан доступ к файлу или к одной из его родительских папок), и «NO», если не сможет.

Примеры:

Пример 1:

**Ввод:**

```
1    
/Temp/Data    
1    
/Secret/Temp/Data
```

**Вывод:**

```
NO
```

**Пример 2:**

**Ввод:**

```
1    
/User/Documents/Secret/Data    
1    
/Secret/Data
```

**Вывод:**

```
NO
```

**Пример 3:**

**Ввод:**

```
3    
/home/alex    
/home/ivan/Documents    
/var/www    
3    
/home/alex/HarryPotter8.doc    
/home/ivan_urgant/game.exe    
/www/index.html
```

**Вывод:**

```
YES    
NO    
NO
```

Не до конца понимаю, почему, но мой код работает неправильно, тестировщик на сайте вводит какое - то непонятное значение:

```
50
/FO/kjakpLOTdmFWwh/Bq_nLz/pCpoPenjngfeZ/BwVyBzcvGiNfZo
/RhYWgv/MTC/NRqmmp
/Hf/Djy/uxDTTyaQvrGGqdlaV
/cznCtwWEvIqGMKVZg
/xe/JjwFrdlAcWtCyVg/SQroWr
/sOzcSXrfYqZSfQbrOK
/GmIrMepgRMVzVXj/c
/t.hteYT/TVGeL/MifkfcGREBN_b
/pqHuz/iwE/loosaYuoNpjr/MW.swprIdQWSodmuK
/JyBNOFchz/akfQleWvlhfim/rXLjLrZSmDp/CrlKjPFs/qwuzaqNehg_jA
/OyifxVUoaR/p/_nk_X.UVJWsbDCQPvm/rjbCeIiJwSAPhCN_/cSGZD_EWXPrpptAJ
/dfrj.MLJjsUXtf
/SoMaiRf/LwJLgCrZNQcjw
/ZWCUqQGZ/qSGlxRvhylEUYa.NhlrF/Ef_paDyN_cVdZnMG_r/QtzcjXmWHFBCB.Vgip/Cb
/Oa
/.WOJsrtaxgxUVZl/dBfm_gFdKtg/FmhiavLQHe
/tTxNvsxXHhYPfApz/xlRdLmQ
/SqBLrJMtdQYg/_YCTJDHI/_qPdBR_wwW
/RXdmDwyx.LNdJl/.rkS/aza/seezH.arH_smLAmiaE/qLVPq
/lFb
/euqirpTPps.GHnFEmAR/XoNyDl._JkzWPmoko/tQs_moTpzevXLt/wbEpYPsuWep/wfYrnQpHBGysUNLU
/ggwmimONlrOgefVNrm/reNasWDpRXrryv/BQFrYip.gfoOfPQ/NDkWVYlwyBFhdUeQYHs
/mqybBN/MWgUpDCUlPjguToxcK
/qsGqddiDsnmUtfWQ/UoKkNvrQdqzOMcv/ceGgorwEqsmikSALMl/YRk.xM
/oYAZJmRVX/HwbwVeRhP_ZVnSU.S.LK
/fXgduWMgecoLDUlS/AKCbzCOmWRBhqE_ZSoLP/VwpEmutauPQxb
/VnEBEaNNatk/EH/VBO/auucOsKDfKTOqBU/DamOlv
File is too long to be displayed fully
```

И тогда у меня неправильно, я просто хочу узнать, может есть какой-нибудь более простой и правильный способ решения задачи?

Вот такой код у меня получился:

```
dict_of_permissions = {}
inquiries = []
answers = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    text = input()
    dict_of_permissions[text] = text.split('/')[1:]
for i in range(int(input())):
    inquiries.append(input().split('/')[1:])
for i in inquiries:
    counter_1 = 0
    for j in dict_of_permissions:
        counter_2 = 0
        if len(dict_of_permissions[j]) > len(i):
            answers.append('NO')
            continue
        else:
            for n in range(len(a[j])):
                if dict_of_permissions[j][n] == i[n]:
                    counter_2 += 1
        if counter_2 == len(dict_of_permissions[j]):
            answers.append('YES')
            break
        counter_1 += 1
    if counter_1 == len(dict_of_permissions):
        answers.append('NO')
print('\n'.join(answers))
```

Comment: В образцах ввода и вывода присутствуют пустые строки, которых, скорее, всего не должно быть. Думаю, они добавились во время копирования.

Comment: Не должны, я просто не понял, как тут нормально разделять строки :/

Comment: Не нужно писать в заголовок всякую ерунду

Comment: Почему это ерунда?

Comment: Ограничение по использованию модулей нужно добавлять в текст вопроса, не в заголовок.

Comment: Я бы так написал: _"В учебных целях требуется обойтись базовыми средствами языка, без импортирования специализированных модулей"_.

Comment: Убрал лишние переносы строк. "Непонятное значение" это тест, который ваша программа не прошла. Так как текст длинный, то в конце написано "File is too long to be displayed fully".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Файловая система является иерархической по своей сути и работать с ней удобнее соответствующим образом.

   Набор путей

   ```
   /home/alex
   /home/ivan/Documents
   /var/www
   ```

   можно представить в виде следующего дерева

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Имея такой набор для проверки

   ```
   /home/alex/HarryPotter8.doc 
   /home/ivan_urgant/game.exe 
   /www/index.html
   ```

   поочерёдно разбиваем каждый путь на два части: `директории`, `имя файла` и проверяем есть ли данный путь в дереве с разрешениями. Важно отметить, что для `/home/alex/HarryPotter8.doc` не обязательно иметь полное соответствие в файловом дереве, достаточно открытой родительской директории на каком-либо уровне, например `/home`. Если пользователь имеет права доступа на директорию `/home`, то по условию задачи он имеет право доступа ко всем вложенным файлам и директориям как-то: `/home/alex/...`, `/home/ivan/...` и т.д.
3. Исходя из предыдущего пункта получается, что в дереве разрешений достаточно держать лишь открытые директории максимально верхнего уровня (кроме случаев, когда указан конкретный файл):

   ```
   /home/alex
   /home/ivan/Documents
   /                    # открываем полный доступ ко всем файлам
                        # все предыдущие правила становятся
                        # ненужными
   ```

   Или такой случай

   ```
   /home
   /home/alex            # оба этих правила ни на что не влияют   
   /home/ivan/Documents  # так как есть более глобальное
   ```

   Для этого я завёл объект `Directory`, который имеет флаг `opened`: при добавлении директории (без файла) в дерево разрешений, она помечается как открытая. При последующих добавлениях, если новый путь проходит через директорию с флагом `opened`, его добавление на ней завершается, таким образом позволяя не писать в дерево ненужные поддиректории.

**Моё решение**

```
class Directory:
    def __init__(self, name, opened=False):
        self.name = name
        self.opened = opened
        self.childs = {}

class Permission_tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Directory('/')

    def add(self, path):
        basename, filename = split_path(path)
        cur_dir = self.root

        for dir_name in basename:
            if cur_dir.opened == True:
                break

            if dir_name not in cur_dir.childs:
                cur_dir.childs[dir_name] = Directory(dir_name)  

            cur_dir = cur_dir.childs[dir_name]
        else:
            if filename:
                cur_dir.childs[filename] = True
            else:
                cur_dir.opened = True

    def check(self, path):
        basename, filename = split_path(path)
        cur_dir = self.root
        message = "NO"

        for dir_name in basename:
            if cur_dir.opened == True:
                message = "YES"
                break

            if dir_name not in cur_dir.childs:
                break

            cur_dir = cur_dir.childs[dir_name]
        else:
            if filename in cur_dir.childs or cur_dir.opened == True:
                message = "YES"

        return message

def split_path(path):
    basename = []   
    filename = None
    if path != '/':
        path_lst = path.split('/')
        if '.' in path_lst[-1]:
            basename = path_lst[:-1]
            filename = path_lst[-1]
        else:
            basename = path_lst

    return basename, filename

def make_permission_tree(num):
    tree = Permission_tree()
    for _ in range(num):
        path = input()
        tree.add(path)

    return tree

def check_permission(tree, num):
    for _ in range(num):
        path = input()
        print(tree.check(path))

def solve():
    permission_num = int(input())
    permission_tree = make_permission_tree(permission_num)  

    check_num = int(input())
    check_permission(permission_tree, check_num)

solve()
```

**Тестирование**

**Input**

```
3
/home/alex
/home/ivan/Documents
/var/www
3
/home/alex/HarryPotter8.doc
/home/ivan_urgant/game.exe
/www/index.html
```

**Output**

```
YES
NO
NO
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, по идее, эту задачу можно решить как-то без использования ооп и функций, но в условии про классы и функции ничего не говорилось, так что, я думаю, это решение может пройти.

Comment: @TAWER768 1) Без классов можно, но с ними удобнее. Я начал в процедурном стиле и упёрся в необходимость отмечать открытую директорию каким-то образом. Можно было сделать так, чтобы конечные директории в дереве указывали на слово "Opened", что не совсем удобно, так как они могут указывать и на файлы - нужно писать код для их различия. 2) Что касается функций, то наврядли у вас есть такое ограничение - функции это базовая вещь, необходимая для читаемости и сокращения дублирования в коде, которые проходят в самом начале. Раз вы уже дошли до задач такой сложности, то фунции должны были пройти.

Comment: Я по программе прошёл словари, множества, списки, условные операторы, циклы, кортежи, методы строк, списков, множеств, словарей и прилагающееся в этому темы, в общем, самые самые базовые знания, по идее, я должен как-то решить эту задачу с этим багажом знаний. функции мне ещё понятны, но ООП для меня - это тёмный лес...

Answer (score 0):

всё гораздо проще

```
data = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    answer = input()
    data[answer] = data.get(answer)
for _ in range(int(input())):
    neww = ''    
    ok = False
    for i in input().split('/'):
        if i:
            neww = neww + '/' + i
        if neww in data:
            ok = True
    if ok:
        print('YES')
    else:
        print('NO')
```

к тому же у **MiniMax** решение неверное, при тесте его кода показывает ту же ошибку, что и у автора вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```
dickt = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    dickt[permis] = dickt.get(permis := input())
for _ in range(int(input())):
    tried = ''
    for i in input().split('/')[1:]:
        tried = f'{tried}/{i}'
        if tried in dickt:
            print('YES')
            break
    else:
        print('NO')
```

код почти как **Марат**, только не используются флаги

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).